# Creating web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I have created very simple ASP.NET web site with web service that is placed in an IIS application pool. Port and address are defined in the site settings of IIS. Web.config is very simple:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

It even does not have information regarding service.

I have looked at other samples of `web.config` and found them much more large:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonHttp" />

      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloDeviceCntrl.AaaComModule.AaaComModule">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/json/Aaacom/" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonHttp" contract="HelloDeviceCntrl.AaaComModule.IAaaComModule" behaviorConfiguration="JsonEndpointBehaviour"/>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/basic/Aaacom/" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultEndpointBehaviour" contract="HelloDeviceCntrl.AaaComModule.IAaaComModule" />
      </service>
      <service name="HelloDeviceCntrl.BaaModule.BaaModule">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/json/Baa/" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonHttp" behaviorConfiguration="JsonEndpointBehaviour" contract="HelloDeviceCntrl.BaaModule.IBaaModule"/>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/basic/Baa/" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultEndpointBehaviour" contract="HelloDeviceCntrl.BaaModule.IBaaModule"/>
      </service>
      <service name="HelloDeviceCntrl.ABCModule.ABCModule" behaviorConfiguration="ABCModuleServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/json/ABC/" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonHttp" contract="HelloDeviceCntrl.ABCModule.IABCModule" behaviorConfiguration="JsonEndpointBehaviour"/>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/basic/ABC/" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultEndpointBehaviour" contract="HelloDeviceCntrl.ABCModule.IABCModule"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ABCModuleServiceBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8001/ABC/get"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JsonEndpointBehaviour">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" faultExceptionEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="DefaultEndpointBehaviour">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <appBaa>
    <add key="anykey1" value="anyvalue1" />
    <add key="ClientBaaProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appBaa>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I got several questions while comparing both configs.

Why my config has no information about port and address? Can I manually add to web.config and overload existing value in site settings?

Should all these configuration lines be edited manually or appended according some project settings?

Comment: Have you checked your web.config as it appears on the server after setting the IIS settings? Usually the settings will change the web.config file if changed in IIS

Comment: No, web.config did not changed after placing in IIS

Comment: Are you referring to web service with an associated 'asmx' handler?

Comment: What do you mean by " 'asmx' handler"? My project contains asmx file that  contains information about web service

Comment: Web service based on asmx does not require any entry in the web.config. The  'services' node in web.config describes WCF services, which is a different and newer way to expose services.

Comment: did you created your application by adding application template via vs, if so, it should give you the web.config you asked for

Answer (score 1):

according to my knowledge,
some of the configuration are appended according to project settings,
and others, you add on your own.
if you want to a certian endpoint with a specific address and specific setings,
or if you want to have a signed or encrypted service.

Answer (score 1):

IP address and port info (called site bindings) are controlled by IIS (or other web servers if you use them), so you won't see them in your web.config (and it is impossible to specify that either, as IIS won't allow you to do so at site or application level for such server level settings).

The sample file you pasted contains information about WCF settings, which is almost irrelevant for your case. Unless you know WCF very well, you should not interpret those settings in your own way and assume ASP.NET should behave the same. That's simply your misunderstanding and should be avoided in all cases.